# customize django admin field based on another drop-down field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a simple Django app with three models:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(("Description"))
    
class ItemType(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(("Description"))
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Plant(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category , on_delete=models.SET_NULL , null=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(ItemType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null = True)
    name = models.CharField()
```

what I need is in the admin panel when I chose a category the type dropdown is filter base on that for example I have category1 and category2 and type1 related to category1 and type2 related to category2 when I choose category1 from the dropdown the type dropdown show only type1

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this the other day, it's a bit of a pain, but doable and I've used it several times since I've come up with this method.

## Steps

1. Add the required information to the context in `render_change_form`.

For your instance I'd imagine you'd want something along the lines of this

```py
def render_change_form(self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url='', obj=None):
    # Implement get_map to return a hierarchical dict that represents your category, item type, and plant 
    context['map'] = self.get_map()
    return super().render_change_form(request, context, add, change, form_url, obj)
```

2. Hide rows that can't be filed yet.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    django.jQuery("div.field-item_type").css('display', '');
    django.jQuery("div.field-plant").css('display', '');
});
```

3. Add event listeners to update dependent fields

```
# When category is changed, you'll need to update options for item_type  and plant
django.jQuery("select[name=category]").change(function () {
    let category = django.jQuery(this)
    update_item_type(category)
    update_plant(django.jQuery('select[name=category]'))
});

# When item_type is changed, you'll only need to plant options
django.jQuery("select[name=item_type]").change(function () {
    let item_type = django.jQuery(this)
    update_plant(item_type)
});
```

4. implement `update_item_type` and `update_plant` to update options on the respective fields

They'll look something like this

```js
function update_item_type(plant) {
    let starting_item_type = django.jQuery("select[name=item_type]").val()

    if (plant.val() === '') {
        django.jQuery("div.field-item_type").css('display', 'none');
    } else {
        let item_type_dict = {{ item_type_dict|safe }};
        let item_type_dom = django.jQuery('#id_item_type');

        item_type_dom.text('')

        django.jQuery.each(item_type_dict[plant.val()], function(index, element) {
            item_type_dom.append('<option value="' + element[0] + '">' + element[1] + '</option>');
        });

        django.jQuery("div.field-item_type").css('display', '');

        django.jQuery("select[name=item_type]").val(starting_item_type)
    }
}
```

Access your dictionary from Django land like this

```js
let map = {{ map|safe }};
```

## Follow-Up

I probably should create a Django package to do this automatically. If anyone knows of one already I'd be interested to hear about it.